# Which definitions of "local module" have gotten traction?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, soft-question, modules, definitions

It seems like "local module" has been defined a lot of ways:

1. if  has a largest proper submodule. ([This math.se post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262905/what-is-the-example-of-a-module-that-is-local-but-not-endolocal))
2. if it is hollow and has a unique maximal submodule (Singh, Surjeet, and Ashish K. Srivastava. "Dual automorphism-invariant modules." Journal of Algebra 371 (2012): 262-275.)
3. if $M/J(M)$ is simple, where $J(M)$ is the Jacobson radical (intersection of maximal submodules.)
4. if $M/J(M)$ is simple and $J(M)$ is small in $M$.
5. if it is projective and its endomorphism ring is local (Ware, Roger. "Endomorphism rings of projective modules." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 155.1 (1971): 233-256.)
6. if $M$ is finitely generated over a Noetherian local ring and its endomorphism ring is local (Vasconcelos, Wolmer V. "On the radical of endomorphism rings of local modules." arXiv preprint arXiv:1109.0203 (2011).)
7. if $M$ has dual Goldie dimension $1$ (which I think is the same as hollow) and is cyclic (Herbera, Dolors, and Ahmad Shamsuddin. "Modules with semi-local endomorphism ring." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 123.12 (1995): 3593-3600.)

Most seem to get across the points which I think are important: having one maximal submodule that all other proper submodules are contained in.  (Conceivably simply saying "unique maximal submodule" could be insufficient if there is one maximal submodule somewhere and then other submodules not contained in that submodule.  We don't have that issue in ring theory for 'local rings' owing to Krull's theorem.)

I'd like to ask which of these have gained traction generally.  I feel like in my years of reading I never really saw any sort of trend in articles or books about this term. But perhaps I am just not looking at the right material.  No doubt they all have their virtues, I just would ask which one has proven the most prolific and/or useful.

Comment: I'm not saying that these are distinct by any means. I interpret 1 and 2 as equivalent, and probably 4 is equivalent to 1 and 2 as well.  If the dual Goldie dimension 1 really does mean hollow, then modules satisfying $7$ would also satisfy 1,2,4.  Maybe there are some 1-local modules that aren't cyclic, though.